# Git: Can I commit my working directory to a new branch without committing it to a current branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I am working on a project, and had all of my tests passing on the master branch.  I then made some changes, and when everything started failing, I realized that maybe I should have made those changes on a different branch.  Is there a way I can commit the changes to a new branch without committing them to my master branch, so that the master still has my passing tests?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, just create the new branch and check it out:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
```

Then commit any changes you have. They'll be applied to the new, checked-out branch.

Comment: ok great.. I misunderstood that section of the docs.  Thanks!

Comment: You can switch branches generally with modified files without problem, you'll notice it shows a list of modified/added/delete files when you checkout to a different branch as a reminder that the working tree is not clean. I think in few cases you may be prevented from doing so. Here you switch to a new branch so it is safe. When it doesn't work you can try to stash (git stash) and then apply the stash on the other branch, so you have a clean directory when checking out.

Comment: @faB will checkout not reset my working dir to the version of that branch you checkout? Im a bit worried about losing stuff with the checkout command just to be able to commit in another branch

Answer (score 6):

You can stash your current changes (git stash), switch to the new branch and then apply the changes to the new branch using

```
git stash pop
```