# creating git branch and commiting into separate branches

Tags: git, git-branch

noob to git:
expanding on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489559/git-can-i-commit-my-working-directory-to-a-new-branch-without-commiting-it-to-a) question a little

I created a repository and committed my `README.md` to the `master` branch.
My local folder structure is:

```
projectName  
 --README.md  
 -- + part1  
 -- -- README.md  
 -- -- + src  
 -- + part2  
 -- + ...
```

I initialized `git init` in the `projectName` folder and was able to make the commit.

Then I do `git checkout -b part1`.
`cd .\part1` and `git add .\README.md .\src`

When I commit and push `git push -u origin part1` and check my repository my master branch has all the files from `part1` and the `part1` branch has correct files but it contains the `README.md` from the master branch.

After I 'remove' the master README.md I want to commit from branch part1 the files/folders in my local part1 folder. The problem I am having with this is when I commit the actual folder part1 shows up in the part1 branch. I just want the contents to show up.

**EDIT_1**
I want to create multiple branches.  After committing to the `master` branch I do this:
`git checkout -b part1`
When I commit from `part1` I don't want the README.md from the `master` coming along for the ride.  Doing `git rm README.md` deletes the file from my local directory.

**UPDATE**
I was confused about the second part of my own question.  @willoller clarified.

Comment: Branches are not the same as subdirectories or subprojects. Each commit tracks the state of the entire project. If you really want to track each subdirectory separately, you need to either make each subdirectory a repository of its own, or use submodules.

Comment: I'm not trying to track each subdirectory... apologies for the confusion.  I want the branches to follow my subdirectories (in an abstract way only).  I want branch `part1` to coincide to folder `part1`.  When I `git checkout part1` and commit folder items in part1 I want branch `part1` to reflect what I have in the folder.

Comment: Git does not work that way. You track the whole directory with subdirectories. If you want them to be separate, you should make each its own repository.

Comment: @willoller check my edit.  I have seen in github where projects will have multiple branches.  After cloning a repository with multiple branches you can traverse the tree by `git checkout part_x`.  I understand that the clone does not produce 'x' number of folders to coincide with the tree.

Comment: From what I can tell, you need to use your `part1` branch *instead of* using a `part1/` subdirectory. OR, you need to make `part1/` its own repo with its own `master` branch. Remember, a branch is *based on* its parent, so will have all the files that the parent has plus/minus any changes.

Comment: @willoller thanks for the help.  I think I understand my problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command `git checkout -b new_branch` to create a new branch from *current* branch.

So you created your `part1` from `master` and your README.md was copied from `master`.

"-u" creates a relation with remote branch.

If you want push your branch to remote host, you could just use `git push origin my_branch`.

To delete files from branch use `git rm` and commit the changes afterwards.

I hope I've helped.

Comment: `git branch` shows two branches: `master` and `part1`.  Branch `part1` was created exactly as you stated.  `git checkout part1` puts me in `part1` branch.  I don't want the README.md from master in this branch.  Do I just `git rm` before I `git add` part1 files/folders?

Comment: just use "git rm README.md" in part1 and "git commit" to fixing. "git status" show current status of modifications in your current branch

Comment: The problem with `git rm <file>` is that it removes the file from my local directory.  I just want to remove it from the HEAD.  Would this work the same `git reset HEAD README.md` ?

Comment: I see what you mean now.  I'm trying a different approach.

Comment: To remove README.md from HEAD you may use common `rm`(for *nix) and commit changes. README.md will removes only from current branch. After `checkout master` you will see `README.md` in master-branch

Comment: I made some edits to your answer... I don't know if it'll show.  But the main jist is that you did answer my question but it was a little confusing... hence the edit.  Thanks!